# Latex Commands in Julia Markdown

Tags: pdf, julia, latex, markdown

I have a simple Julia Markdown script, that I would like to turn into a PDF using `Weave.jl`:

```
---
title: Just a test
author: Me
date: 2022-01-03
output: pdf_document
---

# Some header
Some text.

\newpage

## Some other header
More text.
```

Now, the crux in that document is the `\newpage` command, which is meant to be executed as a Latex command, i.e. "create a pagebreak". But when using `weave("myfile.jmd", doctype="md2pdf")` Weave (or something else) becomes super smart and translates it to `{\textbackslash}newpage` - a smart way of refusing to let me do exactly what I want to do: Latex commands.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "pandoc2pdf" instead to let pandoc interpret the markdown in the file: `weave("myfile.jmd", doctype="pandoc2pdf")` with your given script works and produces the expected pdf.

---

**Alternate answer:**

Weave documentation mentions that ["md2pdf" uses Julia Markdown](http://weavejl.mpastell.com/stable/publish/), and the [Julia Markdown page](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Markdown/#%5CLaTeX) specifies that LaTeX syntax goes between double backticks.

```
---
title: Just a test
author: Me
date: 2022-01-03
output: pdf_document
---

# Some header
Some text.

``\pagebreak``

## Some other header
More text.
```

This works and produces the intended output. (``` ``\newpage`` ``` errors out for some reason, and I'm not comfortable enough with LaTeX to figure out why.)

Comment: Hm, I don't (wanna) have access to my computer right now, but I think this is not the answer. I did try to use "pandoc2pdf" and it didn't work. And I also tried the double backticks - they produced a Latex math environment, to which jlings hack is the solution. Did you actually try these solutions? And if yes, can you let me know what Julia version and what weave.jl version you are on?

Comment: Yeah, I tried them both before posting. Julia 1.7.1, Weave 0.10.10.

Comment: Is your actual file more complex and this is just a MWE in the question? Maybe there's something else in the file that stops the pandoc2pdf option from working. Or if the script in the question itself doesn't work, I'd be curious to know what your Julia and Weave versions are too. Other possibly relevant version numbers on my end: `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998`, `pandoc 2.9.2.1`

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what mistake I made in the first place. You were right: `"pandoc2pdf"` works. Thanks. The double backticks however do not work, and that is kind of expected. The documentation (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Markdown/) says that text surrounded by double backticks is displayed "**mathematics** using Latex", and this is what you see in the created .tex file as well: double backticks are turned into surrounding `$` signs.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. FTR, the double backticks do work for me with `\pagebreak`, just not with `\newpage`, as I mentioned in the answer. I rechecked it now just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I tested and here's the workaround:

```
$\]\pagebreak\[$
```

source: https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl/issues/249

Comment: While the workaround "works", it is indicative of a fundamental error in the Julia weaver.  You just don't have that issue with plain `pandoc`.  <shrug>

Comment: Yeah, looking at the tex file that is created I also came to this idea, but it is super hideous and hacky. I guess this is going to become my last resort if everything else fails.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel but how would you execute Julia blocks and render results if you just use plain `pandoc`?

Comment: I guess it trades one feature (being able to deal with Julia code) off for one bug (or 'variation to the spec' or 'misfeature' whatever you want to call it) of not dealing with markdown as other parsers / converters do who take the latex code as is.   It is apparently documented so all good.

Answer (score -2):

That may be your rendering engine.  This is tagged `julia` and you state using a `.jmd` file.

I happen to use this idiom of injecting 'plain LaTeX' a lot so I just saved your file 'as is' as `foo.Rmd` and used my usual [shorthand caller for Rmarkdown](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/render.r) on it:

[image]

I would recommend decomposing the commands as much as you can, and maybe try just `pandoc` on it too.  You may find what wrapped that stray command.

---

As per the other answer, it simply is a bug in `weave.jl`. It should not do that yet it does.

The answer by @SundarR suggests a workaround using a different subrender (just how I had hinted at `pandoc`) as well as a (required for this "dialect" of markdown?) workaround with two backticks.